# Java applet blocked on our site?

Tags: java, applet, certificate

For my education I often have to program math exercises for our site, which will be used in schools.

I had to port a .swf file to java applet, mainly because the .swf ran really slow.
The game/excercise worked fine in both Eclipse and my localhost, but when we put it on the site it always got blocked by Java.

I have read that you need a certificate, but that self signed certificates dont work.
I have tried to do it (Not sure if I was succesful), and the applet was still blocked.

What am I supposed to do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try Java Web Start instead of applets?

You chan check it at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/applet-migration-139512.html

Comment: I changed my html to the code listed on that site, and it's still being blocked.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_blocked.xml

> Java has further enhanced security to make the user system less
>   vulnerable to external exploits. Starting with Java 7 Update 51, Java
>   does not allow users to run applications that are not signed
>   (unsigned), self-signed (not signed by trusted authority) or that are
>   missing permission attributes.

So, from Java 7 Update 51, users cannot run unsigned application (without a certificate), self-signed application (applications signed with a certificate that doesn't come from trusted authority), or applications missing Permission Attribute.

As the documentation says about self signed applications,

> Applications of this type present the highest level of risk because
>   publisher is not identified and the application may be granted access
>   to personal data on your computer.

Also, as stated in the documentation, if you can still use self signed applications you need to add it to the exception site list,

> As a workaround, you can use the Exception Site list feature to run
>   the applications blocked by security settings. Adding the URL of the
>   blocked application to the Exception Site list allows it to run with
>   some warnings.

Comment: Actually, both me and my colleague added the URL to the exception site list, and it's still being blocked...